# What are the markings on Diaval's face and body?

Tags: maleficent

In Disney's Maleficent, Maleficent's crow-human sidekick, Diaval, has a bunch of markings over his face and chest in human form. They are scar-like, but seem too symmetrical to be accidental.

Is there any info on what they are/ if they have any special significance?

[image]

Comment: I assumed they were intended to portray feathers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the film's Director, the scarification on Diaval is intended to represent feathers:

> "I designed most of the creatures myself," director Robert Stromberg
>   says. It's not really a surprise: Stromberg's contributions in art
>   direction won him two Academy Awards back-to-back for his work in
>   James Cameron's Avatar and Tim Burton's Alice and Wonderland. **"Every
>   time he changed into a different creature, I wanted there to be this,
>   like, resonance of the bird in that creature,"** he explains. "So, when
>   he changes into a wolf - if you look closely - the the nose is
>   slightly beak-like, the feet are bird-like."
>
> As such, there's always an element of a feather left behind, even when
>   he turns into a real animal. "When he turns into a horse," Stromberg
>   says, "We had an actual horse and did a prosthetic horse-face that had
>   a beak quality to it and the mane was actually made of feathers."
>
> As such, Diaval's transition into a human or different animal isn't
>   seamless. **"There are always the remnants,"** Stromberg says. **"Even
>   as a human, there are still some remnants of him as a bird."**

In an [interview with Collider](http://collider.com/sam-riley-maleficent-interview/#Svu88H1PHRE80U60.99) Sam Riley, the actor who plays Diaval said that the original makeup effect was going to be much more pronounced:

> **RILEY:**  *We did tests that were much more extremely bird-like versions.  **It went from being very bird-like to being what it is.  It
>   gradually toned down.***

You can see the earlier makeup 'look' on this poster shot, as compared to the design they ultimately went with:

[image]